# gstreamer dependencies in HandBrake on fedora

Tags: fedora, video, video-encoding, gstreamer

I'm running HandBrake on Fedora 23.  The "show preview" feature is not able to actually play video, raising two popups:  "Missing GStreamer plugin: MPEG-4 AAC Decoder" and "Missing GStreamer plugin: H.264 (Main Profile) Decoder".

In attempts to fix this expediently, I have installed:

```
gstreamer-plugins-bad-nonfree-0.10.23-3.fc22.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-0.10.23-28.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-tools-0.10.36-13.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-extras-0.10.23-28.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-good-0.10.31-15.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-devel-0.10.36-13.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.6.2-1.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-fc-0.2-11.fc23.x86_64
PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin-1.0.11-1.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-ffmpeg-0.10.13-15.fc22.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.23-7.fc22.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.6.2-1.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-good-extras-0.10.31-15.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-0.10.36-13.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-python-0.10.22-9.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.6.2-1.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer1-1.6.2-1.fc23.x86_64
libnice-gstreamer1-0.1.13-2.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-base-devel-0.10.36-13.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.36-13.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer-rtsp-0.10.8-10.fc23.x86_64
```

yet none are the magic package that contains the plugin it seeks.

Does someone know the specific packages for Fedora 23 it's looking for?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

answer:

```
gstreamer1-libav-1.6.1-2.fc23.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-freeworld-1.6.1-1.fc23.x86_64
```

make sure to restart HandBrake also